# Method returning task behaving synchronously in C# console app

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

In a C# console app, I have a repo class with a couple of async methods:

```
public class SomeRepo
{
   internal Task<IList<Foo>> GetAllFooAsync() 
   { 
       // this is actually fake-async due to legacy code.
       var result = SomeSyncMethod();
       return Task.FromResult(result);
   }

   public Task<IList<Foo>> GetFilteredFooAsync()
   {             
       var allFoos = await GetAllFooAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
       return allFoos.Where(x => x.IsFiltered);
   }
}
```

In `Program.cs`:

```
var someRepo = new SomeRepo();
var filteredFoos = someRepo.GetFilteredFooAsync(); // no await
// a couple of additional async calls (to other classes) without await..
// .. followed by:
await Task.WhenAll(filteredFoos, otherTask, anotherTask).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

What is baffling me is that if I place a break point on the 2nd line in `Program.cs`, the call to `someRepo.GetFilteredFooAsync()` does not proceed to the next line, but instead is stuck until the operation is complete (as though it was synchronous). Whereas if I change the call to `GetAllFooAsync` (in `GetFilteredFooAsync`) to be wrapped within a `Task.Run`:

```
public class SomeRepo
{
   internal Task<IList<Foo>> GetAllFooAsync() { // ... }

   public Task<IList<Foo>> GetFilteredFooAsync()
   {             
       var allFoos = await Task.Run(() => GetAllFooAsync).ConfigureAwait(false);
       return allFoos.Where(x => x.IsFiltered);
   }
}
```

..the operation works as expected this way. Is it because `GetAllFooAsync` is actually synchronous, but imitating an asynchronous workflow?

EDIT: Reworded the title and added the internals of `GetAllFooAsync` as I've realized they could be the culprit of the issue.

Comment: In console applications SynchronizationContext returns to thread pool.
In ASP.NET and Win Forms - it is the same thread.
This is no longer a case for .NET core, but for .NET framework you have to care

Comment: I think you need async/await in `GetAllFooAsync` - the sync operation is in this method. `return await Task.FromResult(result);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got some good answers that describe [how `async` doesn't make things asynchronous, how `async` methods begin executing synchronously, and how `await` can act synchronously if its task is already completed](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

So, let's talk about the design.

```
internal Task<IList<Foo>> GetAllFooAsync() 
{ 
  // this is actually fake-async due to legacy code.
  var result = SomeSyncMethod();
  return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

As noted, this is a *synchronous* method, but it has an asynchronous signature. This is confusing; if the method is not asynchronous, it would be better with a synchronous API:

```
internal IList<Foo> GetAllFoo()
{ 
  // this is actually fake-async due to legacy code.
  var result = SomeSyncMethod();
  return result;
}
```

and similar for the method that calls it:

```
public IList<Foo> GetFilteredFoo()
{             
  var allFoos = GetAllFoo();
  return allFoos.Where(x => x.IsFiltered);
}
```

So now we have synchronous implementations with synchronous APIs. The question now is about consumption. If you are consuming this from ASP.NET, I recommend consuming them synchronously. However, if you are consuming them from a GUI application, then you can use `Task.Run` to offload the synchronous work to a thread pool thread, and then treat it as though it were asynchronous:

```
var someRepo = new SomeRepo();
var filteredFoos = Task.Run(() => someRepo.GetFilteredFoo()); // no await
// a couple of additional async calls (to other classes) without await..
// .. followed by:
await Task.WhenAll(filteredFoos, otherTask, anotherTask).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Specifically, I do *not* recommend using `Task.Run` to implement, e.g., `GetAllFooAsync`. [You should use `Task.Run` to call methods, not to implement them](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html), and `Task.Run` should mostly be used to call synchronous code from a GUI thread (i.e., not on ASP.NET).

Answer (score 3):

Presence of `async`keyword doesn't make a method asynchronous it just signals compiler to make conversion the code of the method into state machine class which is ready to be used with asynchronous flows. Effectively a method becomes asynchronous when it does an asynchronous operation such as I/O, offloading work to another thread, etc., and in that case it consists of 3 parts: the synchronous part which precedes an asynchronous operation, call of asynchronous operation which initiates the operation and returns control to calling thread, and a continuation. In your case the last two parts are absent so your call is synchronous.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it because GetAllFooAsync is actually synchronous, but imitating an asynchronous workflow?

Yes, `Task.FromResult` returns a task that is immediately `RanToCompletion` so it is synchronous. People often forget that Tasks may in some cases already be complete when they are returned and therefore do not run asynchronously.

> [This method creates a Task object whose Task.Result property is result and whose Status property is RanToCompletion. The method is commonly used when the return value of a task is immediately known without executing a longer code path. The example provides an illustration.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks)

Comment: Using Task.Run solely to convert sync to async is generally considered bad practice but in a console app is it not so bad as if it were asp.net. I might suggest you kick off your truly async calls, run your synchronous operation, then await all the async tasks since it appears you do not require its result as input to other operations.

Comment: Thank you for this, I unfortunately do not have "truly async calls" to fallback over, which is why my solution ended up like this in the first place.